# How can I find the setting for a Windows 10 upgrade screen? (picture included)

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I am currently trying to automate the Windows 10 upgrade process for some computers around the office. The problem is Windows 10 always resets default apps after the upgrade process has been completed.

In the Windows 10 upgrade process, there is a question about selecting default apps (see picture link below). I was wondering where can I find this setting to automate it? Is it a Registry value? Or any ideas would be helpful thanks!

edit: forgot to mention I am on Windows 8.1

[image]

Comment: The screenshot you provided isn't from Windows 8.1, it is from Windows 10, hence the reason its offering to use Edge.  The screen does not exist on Windows 8.1  Once you upgrade to Windows 10 you can view that screen.

Comment: @ramhound Yes, I will be upgrading the computers from 8.1 to windows 10. Hence, why I am talking about the Windows 10 upgrade process. I am automating the process but the default apps keep resetting. I'm wondering where I can find this setting in the Registry or as a file in the ISO so that I can add steps in the automation to leave the default apps alone

Comment: See this page...https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/deploy/upgrade-to-windows-10-with-the-microsoft-deployment-toolkit

Comment: @moab This is exactly the concept our team is working for an automated process to upgrade each of our computers. A minor issue is we can't figure out how to automate the screen of the image posted in the original post, the Default apps screen. It is small that Chrome and Acrobat get reset to Microsoft Edge, but it is very tedious to switch every computers default back.